# Pattern Matching with @ on Implemented Trait?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
sealed trait Request

sealed trait HasProxy extends Request
sealed trait HasFoo extends Request

case object One extends HasProxy with HasFoo
case object Two extends HasFoo
case object Three extends HasProxy with HasFoo
case object Four extends HasFoo
case object Five extends HasProxy
```

I defined a function that accepts a `HasFoo` type.

```
def f(x: HasFoo) = ???
```

Finally, I attempted to write a function that, given a `Request`, will pattern match on the `HasFoo` cases, i.e. `One`, `Two`, `Three`, and `Four`.

```
scala> def foo(request: Request) = request match {
     |   case xxx @ (One | Two | Three | Four ) => f(xxx)
     | }
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Request
 required: HasFoo
         case xxx @ (One | Two | Three | Four ) => f(xxx)
                                                     ^
```

However, the above failed.

They each have `HasFoo` in common, but I'm not sure how that applies to pattern matching.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> lub ( List( typeOf[One.type], typeOf[Two.type],
     |             typeOf[Three.type], typeOf[Four.type] )
     | )
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = HasFoo with Serializable with Product
```

Rather than calling `f(_)` for each pattern match of `One ... Four`

```
scala> def foo(request: Request) = request match {
     |  case One => ???
     |  case Two => ???
     |  ...
     |  case _   => ???
     | }
foo: (request: Request)Nothing
```

**or** checking the run-time type, i.e. `case xxx : One | Two | Three | Four`:

```
scala> def foo(request: Request) = request match {
     |  case (_: One.type | _: Two.type | _: Three.type | _: Four.type ) => ???
     | }
```

do I have any better alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's arguably a bug or at least an undesirable limitation in the compiler's type inference, but in general if the compiler fails to understand what the actual type of something is--and here you can be really sure--you can just cast to the correct type:

```
case xxx @ (One | Two | Three | Four ) => f(xxx.asInstanceOf[HasFoo])
```

Yes, it's inelegant and possibly unsafe if it's modified in the future, but you can almost completely solve that issue with comments.

If you want the compiler to ensure that the cast is correct, pattern match on that and use a guard clause to reject anything that isn't what you want, e.g.:

```
case xxx: HasFoo 
     if (xxx match { case One | Two | Three | Four => true
                     case _ => false
     }) => f(xxx)
```

Comment: `but you can almost completely solve that issue with comments.` - that seems a bit optimistic to me.

Comment: I should've bitten my tongue perhaps - I know that you've answered innumerable StackOverflow scala questions & have contributed much to the Scala language. I hope that my comment wasn't taken wrongly, @RexKerr.

Comment: @KevinMeredith - Eh, well, maybe I am being overly optimistic.  This is a special case of a pattern that, regrettably, occurs fairly often (e.g. in the Scala library), and rarely produces painful outcomes.  (It has, however, produced painful outcomes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match on anything that's a `HasFoo`, then there's the obvious:

```
def foo(request: Request) = request match {
  case xxx: HasFoo => f(xxx)
  case _ => ???
}
```

Since `One`, `Two`, `Three` and `Four` all extend `HasFoo`, the first case will match all four types; but not `Five`.